# Proof that $ker \ [A, B] \subset im \begin{bmatrix} B^T \\ A^T \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to proof that $ker \ [A, B]=im \begin{bmatrix} B^T \\ A^T \end{bmatrix}$ for $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfying $AB^T+BA^T=0$ and $rk [A, B] = n$. That the image is contained in the kernel is immediately seen, but I did not see the other direction. I think that I have to use the fact that $(ker \ T)^\perp= im \ T$. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $[A,B]$ ? Is it just concat ?

Comment: @dezdichado Jes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $[A,B]$ is not the commutator and is just a block matrix (in order for the matrix/vector sizes to make sense).

Since you have one containment already proven, it suffices to show that the dimensions of these two vector spaces are equal. We know that the rank of $[A~~B]$ is $n$, and this is equal to the rank of $$[A~~B]^T = \begin{bmatrix}A^T\\B^T\end{bmatrix}$$
which is the same as the rank of $$\begin{bmatrix}B^T\\A^T\end{bmatrix}$$ by using elementary row swaps.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Yes, from this point, it is clear, that the dimension of $im [B, A]^T$ is $n$. But I was hoping that there is an direct argument, why all elements in the kernel are contained in the image. My plan is to show a similar result for infinite dimensional spaces and there I can't use an dimensional argument.

Comment: What would be the result for infinite-dimensional spaces? As written, the rank condition is necessary (so for a direct containment argument you would need to use this rank condition somehow).

Comment: I know that the rank condition is necessary. In my case, a similar condition in terms of kernels and images is given. The problem is that I don't know the direct argument in the finite dimensional case.